# Split window & Fuzzy finder path with Nerdtree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, plugin-ctrlp

Say I have one window open displaying folder *foo*. Then I open a new window by doing `:vs ~/bar`. Then I get a Nerdtree, and when using Ctrlp's fuzzyfinder by doing `,,`. I expect the files displayed to be the path of folder *bar*, but instead I get files for folder *foo*.

How can I make Ctrlp display the files for the right folder? Is there any other command than `:vs` I should be using?

One solution that works is opening a file in the *bar* folder. But I don't really want to fill up my buffer list with files I'm not using.

I'm using `dotvim`.

Comment: Tried `:set autochdir` ?

Comment: @SibiCoder: That seems to show all files from my home folder, not the `bar` folder

Comment: You might try setting path to include files from certain path permanently. Do you want only the current folder temporarily?

Comment: @SibiCoder: No, I want it like that always and not for specific folders. Sometimes I want to see code from different repos in two windows next to each other.

Comment: Read this https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/150

Comment: @SibiCoder That seems to just change the working directory. Which would be fine if it was for only one window. But it seems to affect all of them.

Comment: Did you tried `:set autochdir` after giving `:vsp ~/bar/`? Note the slash at the end. If that works, then we can use a autocommand like BufEnter and perform automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41688/discussion-between-dan-klasson-and-sibicoder).